# Raw Querystring in ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In razor mvc helper, I can provide a querystring to ActionLink as a name value pair e.g. `new {x = "something"}`

How can I pass a querystring which is raw data and not name value e.g. if I have abc, I want it to show as `<a href="mylink?something">` instead of `<a href="mylink?x=something">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Url.Action` html helper method along with the anchor tag markup.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Add", "Home")/something">Test</a>
```